# Neo4j - funcionamento do cluster

Tags: neo4j

Alguem sabe informar como o cluster Neo4j faz o "keep alive" entre os nós?

Sei que tem os parametros `ha.tx_push_factor` (quantidade de *slaves* que o *master* força o *commit*) e o `ha.pull_interval` (intervalo que o *master* puxa as transações do *master*).

Mas como o cluster sabe que um nó não está mais ativo (tanto faz se for *master* ou *slave*), por exemplo, em caso de falhas de conectividade entre os nós?

Answer (score -1):

O cluster Neo4j utiliza o protocolo de "heartbeats" para monitorar o estado dos nós do cluster. Cada nó do cluster envia periodicamente "heartbeats" para os outros nós do cluster, indicando que está ativo e disponível. Se um nó não receber um "heartbeat" de outro nó por um determinado período de tempo, ele considera que o nó está inativo e toma medidas para substituí-lo no cluster.

O intervalo entre os "heartbeats" é configurável através do parâmetro ha.heartbeat_interval, que especifica o intervalo em segundos entre os "heartbeats" enviados pelos nós do cluster. O valor padrão é 1 segundo.

Além disso, o cluster também utiliza o protocolo de "election" para escolher o novo master em caso de falha do atual master. Quando um nó detecta que o master atual está inativo, ele inicia o processo de "election" para escolher um novo master entre os nós do cluster. Os nós do cluster votam entre si e o nó com o maior número de votos é eleito o novo master. O intervalo entre as eleições é configurável através do parâmetro ha.election_timeout, que especifica o intervalo em segundos entre as eleições. O valor padrão é 5 segundos.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).